# Update record using HttpPut method only specific field

Tags: rest-api, api, callout, apexrest, rest-service

I am trying to create Callout class to allow external system to update records,like below

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/OppleadUpdate/*')
global with sharing class test_Callout2 {
    @HttpPut
    global static Lead getleads(test_Callout2.leadWrapper leadwrap){
        RestRequest leadrequest = RestContext.request;
        Map<String, String> leadRequestParams =leadrequest.params;
        //Integer leadlimit = Integer.valueOf(leadRequestParams.get('limit'));

        Lead leads =new Lead();
        leads= [SELECT Id,Salutation,FirstName from Lead 
               ];
        if(leads!=null){
        leads.Salutation=leadwrap.Salutation;
        leads.FirstName=leadwrap.FirstName;
        leads.LastName=leadwrap.LastName;
           
        update leads;
        }
        return leads;
    }
    
    global class leadWrapper{
        public String Salutation; 
        public String FirstName;
        public String LastName;
        // public String CountryName;
        public String Email;
        public Integer TotalBudget;
        //public String Status;
    }

}
```

When I tried to test in Postman at that time if I pass only

```
{
    "leadwrap":
    {
    "Salutation": "Ms.",
    "LastName": "test",
    }
}
```

like above it's updating only these 2 fields with remaining field values becoming null. How can I handle this scenario?

Can you please help me how to handle this in class. I am very new to Standard API.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that everything else is working fine (i.e. you're passing additional data outside of "leadwrap" to be able to get the lead to work on), you simply need to check if each field (in `leadwrap`) is null before setting the corresponding field on your lead.

Ternaries are probably the quickest/simplest approach. e.g.
`leads.FirstName = leadWrap.FirstName == null ? leads.FirstName : leadwrap.FirstName;`

Where the ternary behaves like `result = condition ? value if true : value if false;`

Also, I'd recommend adopting and using a *code style*:

- Be consistent with indentation (for readability)
- Put spaces between things like variables and operators (e.g. `myVar = other + thing` instead of `myVar=other+thing;`, also for readability)
- Use singular variable names for single records, and plural variable names for collections (maps, sets, and lists)
- Make class names "TitleCase" (each word starts with a capital letter)
- Make variable names "camelCase" (each word, except for the first, starts with a capital letter)

Comment: The only downside is you can't tell if the property was omitted or should actually be null.

Comment: Hi @Derek F, Thank you for your advice it's working for me.